# what do I do to enable my Microsoft SQL Server 2008 install and run on my windows7 computer

Tags: sql-server

I tried Installing Microsoft SQL Server 2008 at first, Its installation was going smoothly until I closed my computer to attend to an occasion. Before I tried installing it for a second time, I compressed my C drive(C:) so as to create more storage space. On Installing it again, It couldn't install as a dialog box displayed showing that my attributes doesn't match.

I uncompressed my C: drive and tried installing it again yet it couldn't install. Finally I tried for the last time just to see the image below.

What do I do? My computer is a 32bit OS. and window 7 Ultimate.

[image]

Comment: This is off topic, but i'd uninstall, and re-install. It's the first thing anyone is going to recommend trying to do.

Comment: What version of SQL are you wanting to install? I think 2008 Express would
 install on Win 7 if this link is to be believed: http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2010/sql-server-2008-r2/ If you are looking at standard or enterprise, question is, why are you installing that on Win 7?

Comment: Did you solve your problem? some of us helps you?  If you make a question, please be polite with the people that waste some time with it and give a feedback.

Comment: i tried it but it could not install

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the Hardware and Software Requirements for Installing SQL Server 2008, some conditions are:

> - SQL Server Setup will block installations on read-only or compressed drives.
> - For minimum version requirements to install SQL Server 2008 on Windows Server 2012 or Windows 8, see Installing SQL Server on Windows Server 2012 or Windows 8 (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2681562).

So please read it carefully, you can found it in the MSDN [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506(v=sql.100).aspx)